# How to subtract a row value by Getdate() function

Tags: sql-server-2008

i'm trying to get the difference between getdate() and my value from the column

**S.RefMonthstart** below is the query which i'm trying but, i'm getting an error like

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 10 Operand data type date is invalid
>   for add operator.

```
SELECT dateadd(DAY,0,(CAST(GETDATE()as date))-convert(date,s.RefMonthStart,106))
AS 'Row 
Number'FROM Table1 s
```

here my column RefMonthStart is of type varchar and has values like

> 0
>
> 31
>
> 61

Now how will i come come this error

Comment: getting the difference between dates is usually done with `DATEDIFF`.. are you trying to find the difference in days? months? years? .. also the varchar value of '31' and '61' will fail if you try to convert them, what are these numbers supposed to be representing? are they supposed to be a number of days?

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite your query like this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d,cast(s.RefMonthStart AS DATETIME),GETDATE()) AS 'Row Number' 
FROM Table1 s
```

here is a sample sqlfiddle for the same
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e4b9/1